# get the value of a variable passed in a jquery trigger event

Tags: php, jquery

My main page:

```
  $(function(){
      $('.controls').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');  //which in this case will be "pets"
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:"page="+id,
            url:"controller.php",
            success:function(result){
              $('#content').html(result);
            }
        });
      });
    });

 </script>

 if (isset($_GET['myFave'])){
 ?>
 <script>

  $(function(){
    var animal = "<?php echo $_GET['myFave'];?>";
    $('#pets').trigger('click',[{'myFave':animal}]);
  });
 </script>
<?php
 }
?>
```

controller.php

```
  $page = $_POST['page'];   //which will be "pets"
  require_once($page.".php");
```

pets.php

```
   <table align='center'>
    ////some data
   /// how do i access trigger here?
```

if a user clicks on a url http://server.com?myFave=dog

on my main page i need to trigger the click "pets".

so on main page:

how would i access the value of the params passed in the trigger on pets.php?

Comment: Instead of `$_GET['myFave']` you can use `$page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the value of that variable to `controller.php` so now you have no access to it.

To send it, you could do something like:

main page:

```
$(function(){
      $('.controls').click(function(event, myFave){
                                           ^^^^^^ get the additional parameters you might send in
        var id = $(this).attr('id');  //which in this case will be "pets"
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            // Send all data to the server
            data: {page: id, myFave: myFave},
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ also send this key-value pair
            url:"controller.php",
            success:function(result){
              $('#content').html(result);
            }
        });
      });
    });

 </script>

 if (isset($_GET['myFave'])){
 ?>
 <script>

  $(function(){
    var animal = "<?php echo $_GET['myFave'];?>";
    $('#pets').trigger('click',[animal]);
                               ^^^^^^^^ Add the extra parameter values
  });
 </script>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Then you would have access to it in `pets.php`:

```
$myFave = isset($_POST['myFave']) ? $_POST['myFave'] : null;
```

Alternatively you could use a session to keep that value on the server between requests.